# Laravel Array Keys not Preserved

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

Currently running Laravel 4.1.31.  In the controller an array is built of users with their id as the key:

```
$owners = User::get()->lists('username','id');
```

Printing the owners array out at the controller level would produce the following:

```
print_r($owners)

// Array
// (
//    [1] => user1
//    [2] => user2
//    [4] => user3  <--- key jumps to 4, this is correct
//    [5] => user4
//    [6] => user5
// )
```

However once the array is passed to a view the keys are not preserved, printing it out at the view level produces the following:

```
// Array
// (
//    [1] => user1
//    [2] => user2
//    [3] => user3  <--- key was replaced with 3, this is incorrect
//    [4] => user4       all values from this point on are now shifted
//    [5] => user5
// )
```

There was no 3 key in the original array however once it was passed to the view everything shifted to fill in the gap.  This ends up causing problems as all id's above 2 are now mismatched.  How can the arrays keys be preserved?

Full controller method:

```
public function edit($id) {

  // get the task
  $task = $this->task->find($id);

  // grab all users for owner field
  $owners = User::get()->lists('username','id');

  // grab all projects for project field
  $projects = Project::get()->lists('title','id');

  // add placeholder to beginning of arrays
  array_unshift($owners, 'Select Owner');
  array_unshift($projects, 'Select Project');

  // return show view
  return View::make('tasks.edit', array(
    'task'     => $task,
    'status'   => $this->status,
    'projects' => $projects,
    'owners'   => $owners
  )); 

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the full controller action please?

Comment: This is likely why I haven't used lists. Would it work for you if you changed: `$owners = User::select("username", "id")->distinct()->get();`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Added the method.

Comment: Do a `dd($owners)` before the `array_unshift` and note the results. Then do one after `array_unshift`, do the keys change then or only when sent to `tasks.edit`?

Comment: @TimLewis thats it... `array_unshift` is not preserving the keys.

Comment: Ok, I'll make an answer on how to handle that, 1 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_unshift` changes the keys of your array. It will reset them to sequence of numbers 0,1,2,3,...

Use this to add a value with key `""` at the beginning of your array:

```
$owners = ['' => 'Select Owner'] + $owners;
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, get rid of `array_unshift` on the two arrays. In the view, handle that as follows:

```
<select name="projects">
  <option value="">Select Project</option>
  @foreach($projects AS $project)
  <option value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->title }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Instead of making the first element a generic value, hardcode it **before** processing the @foreach to make a select.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh. Well, since I've never once used Laravel's `Form::*` functions, I didn't know... You make a good point though. I feel like I have more control without using `Form::*`, so I never bothered with it.