# How to Assuming array to another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am going to set an array to another array in PHP but I don't know how. 
[Drop-down list](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists) in Laravel get an array and assume it to $data and then:

```
    $data=array('1' => 'New York', '2' => 'Los Angeles','3'=>'Chicago', '4'=>'Houston')
    echo Form::select('size', $data);
```

This is what I get from Database(Four City):

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [city_id] => 1 [name] => New York ) [1](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists) => stdClass Object ( [city_id] => 2 [name] => Los Angeles ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [city_id] => 3 [name] => Chicago ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [city_id] => 4 [name] => Houston ) ) 1

OK How to use top array that is from Database and assume it to $data (I need first value be **city_id** and second be **name** of city) ?

I used this in my controller:

```
$states=DB::table('cities')->where('parent_id','0')->select('city_id','name')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has the very handy `lists()` function:

```
$data = DB::table('cities')->where('parent_id','0')->lists('name', 'city_id');
```

It will construct an array with the value from one attribute (first argument `name`) and another optional value as key (second argument `city_id`) The second argument can be omitted (then a numerical index will be used)

Comment: Thanks Now I founded this. Thanks for your answer too.

Comment: Can you please tell me How can I add another value at the begging of that array?

Comment: You're welcome. That's funny I just answered a similar question. See if you can make something out of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27932071/1903366)